# Printing Details Report in Rally

Tags: rally

I need to implement a functionality using ExtJs and Ralyy SDK 2.1 for printing the TreeGrid along with details of Userstories, Tasks and Defects same as we get while printing Details report on Summary Pages in Rally Example

[Summary Page Print Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuoUP.png)

Also the expected results screenshot is as follows

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kdQR.png)

Comment: I have tried Rally.ui.plugin.print.GridPrintPage and Rally.ui.plugin.print.RecordPrintPage provided my rally, but not successfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to follow this example to implement it:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/example/printable-grid-board